# Access image from resources in a companion object

Tags: image, kotlin, drawable

Rookie dev here... sorry if the question is too stupid.

I have a class where I use a companion object to create a List. I´m assigning to my companion object a name and an image. I don´t know how to get access to the image which is located in my drawable folder
In my code, I´m assigning a name (through a list of names) and I should be assigning a image to each names. I know I can access to these images through this method

context.resources.getIdentifier("nameOfMyFileImnage","drawable", "com.KhaxApplications.Aristeia_app")

My big issue is that i don´t know how to get access to the context.

This is the code

```
class AristoDataSource {

    companion object {
        val listadoAristos = arrayListOf(
            "maximus", "ball8", "gata", "mushashi", "lunah", "wild_bill", "hexx3r", "parvati")

       
        fun createDataSet(): ArrayList<Aristo> {

            val list = ArrayList<Aristo>()
            for ( item in listadoAristos)
            {list.add( Aristo(
                item,
                context.resources.getIdentifier("myImageFile","drawable", "com.KhaxApplications.Aristeia_app")
            ))}
            return list
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks if advance for any comments here.

Comment: You should pass the context as a parameter to `createDataSet` like `fun createDataSet(context: Context): List<Aristo>` and call it like `AristoDataSource.createDataSet(activity)` (or whatever context you have). You could also store the application context in a global variable when creating the Application, but that can have negative side effects, for example when unit testing.

Comment: Hi Fluidsonic. That´s what I finally did. And I think it worked! :-). I still need to debug some issues in my problem but at least, I can access my image. thank you very much for taking your time replying this questions.

Answer (score 1):

As fluidsonic said, I added context to my createDataSet function and call it from another class passing the context. Error message dissapear.

```
 fun createDataSet(context:Context): ArrayList<Aristo> {

            val list = ArrayList<Aristo>()
            for ( item in listadoAristos)
            {list.add( Aristo(
                item,
                context.resources.getIdentifier("myImageFile","drawable", "com.KhaxApplications.Aristeia_app")
            ))}
            return list
        }

´´´
and calling through createDataSet(Activity)
```